Using Bayesian priors to penalize curve fitting
I am writing a data reduction program for residual gas analysis mass spectrometry. Specifically, I am trying to model gas consumption via ionization as an exponential decay function:
y = a * exp(-p*t) + b

where:

t is the independent variable, time in seconds after gas equilibration t=0
y is the dependent variable, gas intensity in amperes
a, b, and p are fitted parameters

The goal of this curve fitting is to determine the intensity y_0 at the intercept t=0. This represents the quantity of gas that we would have measured if the gas had not needed to equilibrate.
This works well for most analyses, however, on occasion it has a tendency to "overfit" the first few data and produce unrealistically high consumption rates:

40 amu y: [1.00801174e-11 8.60445782e-12 8.74340722e-12 9.63923122e-12
 8.77654502e-12 8.83196162e-12 9.44882502e-12 9.54364002e-12
 8.68107792e-12 9.19894162e-12 9.26220982e-12 9.30683432e-12]
40 amu y_err: [3.55155742e-14 3.03603530e-14 3.08456363e-14 3.39750319e-14
 3.09613755e-14 3.11549311e-14 3.33097888e-14 3.36410485e-14
 3.06279460e-14 3.24368170e-14 3.26578373e-14 3.28137314e-14]
40 amu t: [13.489 19.117 24.829 30.433 35.939 41.645 47.253 52.883 58.585 64.292
 69.698 75.408]

Note that the predicted intercept is 11 orders of magnitude higher than any of the actual data.
One proposed solution to this (which didn't work) was to provide the fitting routine (either curve_fit or lmfit) with the following initial guesses:

While this doesn't work as initial guesses--the curve fitting routine still runs away with the value of p--this initial guess of p is always much more reasonable than that returned by the "optimization" routine.
I have been learning about Bayesian approaches and would like to use these initial guesses and their variances as prior knowledge to penalize fits that stray too far from these guesses--or, at the very least, the initial guess of p.
The problem is that I am completely new to this and utterly lost as to how this would be implemented. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# exponential decay
def model(t, a, b, p):
    return a * np.exp(p * t) + b

# a must be positive; p must be negative
def set_boundaries():
    return [0, -np.inf, -np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf, 0]


# generate the sum term S and the first left-hand side matrix of the linear system lhs1_p
def initial_guess_p_S_and_lhs1_p(t, y):
    S = [0]
    for i in range(1, len(t)):
        S.append(S[i-1] + 0.5 * (t[i] - t[i - 1]) * (y[i] + y[i - 1]))
    S = np.array(S)
    
    lhs1_p = [
        [np.sum(S**2), np.sum(S*t), np.sum(S)],
        [np.sum(S*t), np.sum(t**2), np.sum(t)],
        [np.sum(S), np.sum(t), len(t)]
    ]
    
    return S, lhs1_p

# linearize the problem and generate an initial guess of p
def initial_guess_p(t, y):
    S, lhs1_p = initial_guess_p_S_and_lhs1_p(t, y)
    lhs2 = [
        np.sum(S*y),
        np.sum(t*y),
        np.sum(y)
    ]
    
    init_p, _, _ = np.linalg.solve(lhs1_p, lhs2)
    
    return init_p

# generate the left-hand side matrix of the linear system lhs1_ab
def initial_guess_ab_lhs1_ab(t, init_p):
    return [
        [len(t), np.sum(np.exp(init_p*t))],
        [np.sum(np.exp(init_p*t)), np.sum(np.exp(2*init_p*t))]
    ]


# generate initial guesses of a and b
def initial_guesses_ab(t, y, init_p):
    lhs1_ab = initial_guess_ab_lhs1_ab(t, init_p)
    
    lhs2 = [
        np.sum(y),
        np.sum(y*np.exp(init_p*t))
    ]
    
    init_b, init_a = np.linalg.solve(lhs1_ab, lhs2)
    
    return init_a, init_b


# generate the residuals of the model
def initial_residuals(t, y, a, b, p):
    return y - model(t, a, b, p)


# generate the initial guess of the variance of the residuals
def init_p_error(t, y, init_p, initial_resids):
    S, lhs1_p = initial_guess_p_S_and_lhs1_p(t, y)
    init_p_variance, _, _ = np.linalg.inv(lhs1_p) * np.sum(initial_resids**2)
    
    return init_p_variance

# generate the initial guess of the variance of the residuals
def init_ab_error(t, init_p, initial_resids):
    lhs1_ab = initial_guess_ab_lhs1_ab(t, init_p)
    init_b_variance, init_a_variance = np.linalg.inv(lhs1_ab) * np.sum(initial_resids**2)
    
    return init_a_variance, init_b_variance


# Add the main function to test the above functions
def main():
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    a, b, p = 2.5, 1.0, -0.5
    y = model(t, a, b, p) + 0.1 * np.random.normal(size=t.size)
    
    init_p = initial_guess_p(t, y)
    init_a, init_b = initial_guesses_ab(t, y, init_p)
    
    print(f"Initial guesses: a={init_a}, b={init_b}, p={init_p}")
    
    # Fit the model with initial guesses
    popt, _ = curve_fit(model, t, y, p0=[init_a, init_b, init_p])
    
    # Plotting
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(t, y, label='Data')
    plt.plot(t, model(t, *popt), label='Fit', color='red')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Value')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

EDIT: adding more examples

40 amu p init: -0.14367518985061087 p: -0.6565324927370925
40 amu y: [1.03659297e-11 9.01981636e-12 9.21698536e-12 8.42299856e-12  8.99095476e-12 9.32831176e-12 8.66239446e-12 8.94233696e-12  9.66985026e-12 8.93559296e-12 9.08987596e-12 8.93206396e-12]
40 amu y_err: [4.58060424e-14 3.98911199e-14 4.07573504e-14 3.72694684e-14 3.97643259e-14 4.12464696e-14 3.83209953e-14 3.95507423e-14 4.27471417e-14 3.95211154e-14 4.01989091e-14 3.95056122e-14]
40 amu t: [ 8.908 14.511 20.117 25.833 31.434 37.146 42.648 48.249 53.954 59.586
 65.211 70.822]


40 amu p init: -0.15494649546677705 p: -1.7804944874902089
40 amu y: [1.02342173e-11 9.13542299e-12 8.71434679e-12 9.30896839e-12 9.67921739e-12 8.81455689e-12 9.01517339e-12 9.32982869e-12  9.07950499e-12 9.10221369e-12 9.13479289e-12 9.74699459e-12]
40 amu y_err: [4.52082398e-14 4.03777891e-14 3.85269625e-14 4.11406522e-14 4.27682641e-14 3.89674163e-14 3.98492179e-14 4.12323508e-14 4.01319933e-14 4.02318124e-14 4.03750194e-14 4.30662243e-14]
40 amu t: [ 9.808 15.54  21.056 26.757 32.365 37.967 43.603 49.221 54.934 60.453
 66.158 71.669]

Note that in both cases, the initial guess of p is smaller, therefore more reasonable, than whatever curve_fit comes up with. I therefore want to use this initial guess p and its error as a Bayesian prior.

I don't think that your data here bears any resemblance to an exponential decay curve. The y values seem to be increasing with x for a fair chunk of the domain. Basically, you would have needed data at (substantially) earlier times to pick out the decay part. You seem to be left with the residual constant here. (BTW, why does gas have an "intensity", and why is it being measured in amperes?)

This may have been a particularly noisy example--it's hard to see when the curve is smushing everything like that. I apologize. When I get the chance, I will supplement this with more (and better) examples.

Your example is down in the noise and oscillating wildly at that with a period of ~20s. You need some points in the t ~ 10 and t ~ 6 regime to stand any chance of fitting a meaningful curve. Bayesian methods cannot fix bad data that is as bad as this. They can tip the balance in finding a signal where all classical method have failed though.

I have added more examples with explicit examples of p values between the linearized initial guess and the curve_fit results.

Your data still isn’t remotely close to exponential decay - try plotting it ON ITS OWN, without accompanying curve fit, and you will see that. If there was any exponential decay then it occurred on a far smaller timescale than is available in your data.

The examples above are gibberish. The exponential "fit" is complete nonsense. You need some points nearer to the origin to stand any chance at all of understanding your data. I suggest you plot just your data points in something like Excel and try the simple curve fits available there to understand your problem. The data is rubbish and there is no fancy way of processing these data that can alter that fact.

@Martin Brown : I agree with your judicious comments. Nevertheless in such a case of doudtful validity of the equation model and very large scatter of data I proposed a more "rustic" regression method in my answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658227/reducing-extreme-behavior-in-linear-exponential-decay-hybrid-function/658863?noredirect=1#comment1238803_658863 .

@lastchance : I agree with your judicious comments. Nevertheless in such a case of doudtful validity of the equation model and very large scatter of data I proposed a more "rustic" regression method in my answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658227/reducing-extreme-behavior-in-linear-exponential-decay-hybrid-function/658863?noredirect=1#comment1238803_658863 .

@ohshitgorillas : The  algorithm you cited  comes from  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . But you makes a big error in thinking that "Regression with Integral Equation" (RwIE) was made to provide initial values to classical nonlinear regression. RwIE is made to give approximates of the parametrers. That's all. Of course one can use the results of RwIE to try to slightly improve an usual nonlinear regression. It should be crazy to use a nonlinear regression sotware after RwIE in the cases where the result becomes worse than the result of RwIE alone.

@lastchance to answer your question: In mass spectrometry, gases are ionized to charge them. These ions are directed toward a detector, here a Secondary Electron Multiplier (SEM). When the ions strike the SEM, they cause emission of electrons. These secondary electrons are then amplified through a cascade effect within the SEM, where each electron impact releases more electrons at successive stages. This results in a measurable current on the detector, recorded as an intensity in amperes. The intensity corresponds to the number of ions detected, providing a quantitative measure of gases.

So you are measuring Ar40 for some reason during a pump down or bake out? If you explain what it is you actually want to do it might be possible to answer the question. I used to work for VG Instruments on mass spectrometers of every shape and size. The golden rule is always to get the very best experimental data that you can and resort to exotic analysis techniques like Bayesian and Maximum Entropy only when you have exhausted all other possibilities. Bad data will always be bad data forever...In your case you need to measure data at shorter timescales than 10s!

Measuring closer to t=0 is physically impossible.

Our systems measure helium primarily, we also measure argon as a bellwether to verify the health of the vacuum system. An anomalous argon reading outside of the system's usual range can indicate a problem like a leak.

As commenters have pointed out, the examples provided are extremely noisy and do not really display an exponential decay curve. In these cases, this "overfitting" is a result of curve_fit doing its best given crappy data.
The solution is, therefore, not to try to "domesticate" the exponential decay model with a Bayesian approach, but rather to avoid fitting such noisy trends altogether. This is accomplished by calculating two competing models using the Aikake Information Criteria: the exponential decay model, and the bulk average. The approach with the lowest AIC is used by the program.
In all of the example cases, comparing the exponential AIC to the average AIC yields the knowledge that the "average" is a better approach in all cases.
